# Django Swagger Rest API, tryit now function when api is on different server to ui

Tags: django, swagger

I am trying to document our Django Rest API using Django Swagger Rest API where our API is on different server to UI

Trying to change the TryIt now URL for the curl request as the API is on a different server to the UI

I have tried setting url in get_swagger_view, but this appends ui url before this url
I have tried changing base_path in SWAGGER settings but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you tried absolute url and it didn't work, another way to do that is customize the generator instead of using get_swagger_view function. You can change whatever you need, for instance:

```
from rest_framework import response, schemas
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework_swagger.renderers import OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer

class CustomRenderer(OpenAPIRenderer):
    def get_customizations(self):
        data = super().get_customizations()
        data['host'] = 'yourdomain.com/path'
        return data


@api_view()
@renderer_classes([SwaggerUIRenderer, CustomRenderer])
def swagger_view(request):
    generator = schemas.SchemaGenerator(title='Your title')
    return response.Response(generator.get_schema(request=request))
```

Don't forget to configure this function in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'docs^$', swagger_view)
]
```

Comment: yes, it just seems to add this url to the base url of the ui in the curl request

Comment: @user3608184 I updated the answer. Take a look if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for this where do I place this code? And how do I use it

Comment: @user3608184 Put this code in the same place you were putting before, for example `views.py`. Instead of using the shortcut `swagger_view = get_schema_view(...)` now you have a new `swagger_view` function. Don't forget to configure this function in your urls.py. I added new information in the answer.

Comment: This did not make any difference, the url invoked by curl is the Base Url shown in the UI, it did change the title tho

Comment: @user3608184 really? That's weird because it works for me. Could you edit your question and show us exactly what you did?

Comment: I have followed the example, I created swagger_view.py file with the code exampe with an appropriate title and domain name for "host" then imported the swagger_view into my urls.py, add the url pattern for docs.I have noted that in another post they use basePath tried this as well with no luck

Comment: @user3608184 Try debugging (ipdb) after this line `data = super().get_customizations()`. Change some data and check if there is some difference on the UI.

Comment: given up on django rest swagger, using drf_yasg instead and that works fine